# Perform diff with original pull and latest commit I've made

Tags: git

I cloned a repository (repo_orig) on date1 and my copy lets refer to as (repo_copy).
I've made changes to that clone and commit those changes, but have not pushed those changes.
Other have made changes to the repo_orig and pushed their changes, so the repo I cloned on date1 and the repo today (date2) are different.

I have made a bunch of commits but haven't pushed those changes. I want to perform a diff of all the changes I have made to the original repo, so basically I want to perform a diff of the my local commits and the repo on date1, how do I do this?

If something I said is unclear, please ask me to rephrase in the comments rather than just downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you should check the revision where you started developing from. You could try using the ... notation which will use the parent of two branches for the diff.

Say origin/master has moved forward thanks to your buddies. So... yo fetch and then you could do a diff like this:

```
git diff origin/master...HEAD
```

That will diff from the point where origin/master and your branch diverged up to where your branch is right now.